# How can I check the number of times a character is shown in the array?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to create a program that will tell me how many times a letter appears in the  array, so if the array contains `{'a','c','b','a','b','a'}` it will output:
`a: 3`
`c: 1`
`b: 2`.
I am building this program so I can learn how to think, so I want to do it with the basics only. No `Hashmap` and other more advanced things.

**Edit: here is my answer, I succeeded create the program without** `Hashmap`:

```
public class arrays5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    char [] arr = {'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b','a'};
    char [] letters = new char[arr.length];

    int count = 0;
    char ch = '_';
    boolean isInArray;

    for (int i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        isInArray = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[i] == letters[j])
                isInArray = true;
        }

        if (!isInArray)
            letters[i] = arr[i];
    }

    int amountOfLetters = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        if (letters[i] != '\0')
            amountOfLetters++;
    }

    int index = 0;

    char [] newLetters = new char[amountOfLetters];
    for (int i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
        if (letters[i] != '\0') {
            newLetters[index] = letters[i];
            index++;
        }
    }

    for (int k = 0; k < newLetters.length; k++) {
        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            ch = arr[i];
            count = 0;
            for(int j=i;j<arr.length;j++){
                if(arr[i] == arr[j])
                    count++;
            }

            if (ch == newLetters[k])
                System.out.println(ch + ": " + count);
        }

    }

  }
}
```

I created the temporary arrays so I can know when a `char` has already output and it will not show the same `char` more than once, but it didn't help, the output of this program is:

Comment: Ask the user for input. Read about [`Scanner#next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--).

Comment: I know how to get input.. The problem is how to count each different value

Comment: Use a `Map`, for each key store the number of times it appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do this by using an array index for each element. This way you don't have to know the input but assumed all are small caps.

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] count= new int[26]; // 26 elements for 26 letters
        char[] inputs = {'a','b','a','b','c','a'}; // example input

        for(Character c : inputs){
            count[c-'a'] ++; 
           // if c='b', then c-'a' returns 1, thus increments the count[1].
        }

        for (int i=0; i<26; i++){
            // using if condition I only print the previously encountered letters
            if(count[i]>0)
                System.out.println((char)(i+'a')+":"+count[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

This way time complexity is really low (Only O(number_of_inputs)).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a HashMap. 

 Quick demo:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        char[] inputs = {'a','b','a','b','c','a'};
        HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

        for(Character c : inputs){
            if(map.containsKey(c)){
                Integer i = map.get(c);
                i++;
                map.put(c, i);
            }
            else{
                map.put(c, 1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println(map);        
    }

}
```

will output:

```
{b=2, c=1, a=3}
```

Where they key is your char and the number indicates how often it was in your array.

Comment: Or simply `Integer count = map.get(c); map.put(c, count == null ? 1 : count+1);`

Comment: Actually I misunderstood the question I got and it should have been much simpler, but thank you, it's another new thing for me to learn :)

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you a full solution, however I'll try to guide you.

You can make a [`HashMap<Character, Integer>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

If the `char` already appears in the map, increment it's *key* by one, otherwise, add it to the map.

For example:

```
put('C', 1);
```

Then, assume it's 'C' again, you can do:

```
put('C', get('C') + 1);
```

Since the *key* of 'C' is 1, now when you put it, the key will be 2.

Answer (score 0):

you can read the character using the scanner.next()

```
char c = scan.next().charAt(0);
```

you can change your code like below

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter size of array : ");
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    char[] arr = new char[n];

    //Read inputs to array
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = scan.next().charAt(0);

    }

    //Main Logic
```

to optimize your code (Main Logic ) you can use hash table visit [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html]

Answer (score 0):

In java 8 it's one line:

```
return Arrays.stream(arr).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::valueOf, Collectors.counting()).get(input);
```